# how to open a URL with variable in angularjs ng-grid

Tags: html, angularjs, url

I want to open `http://www.myexample.com/test/index.jsp?Id=ANGULAR_VAR` in a new tab after clicking on a ID column in my ng-grid, here is the code
But it does not work! How can I pass angular variable as a part of URL?

```
    $scope.gridOptionsDeals = {
        data: 'data',
        headerRowHeight: 60,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowSelection: false,
        columnDefs: [{
          width: 90,
          field: 'id',
          displayName: 'id',
          cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>' +
            '<a class="sku-details"  href="http://www.myexample.com/test/index.jsp?Id="+{{row.getProperty("id")}}+" target="_blank">{{row.getProperty("id")}}</a>' +
          '</span></div>'
        },
```

Comment: Pls read documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: "it does not work" is not a very explanatory error message.

Comment: it goes to to this page without any error
http://www.myexample.com/test/index.jsp?Id={{row.getProperty(